# How to create a listview that makes centering the desired element

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm doing something similar to this video: https://youtu.be/fpqHUp4Sag0

With the following code I generate the listview but when using the controller in this way the element is located at the top of the listview and I need it to be centered

```
Widget _buildLyric() {

  return ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => _buildPhrase(lyric[index]),
    itemCount: lyric.length,
    itemExtent: 90.0,
    controller: _scrollController,
  );
}


void goToNext() {
  i += 1;
  if (i == lyric.length - 1) {
    setState(() {
      finishedSync = true;
    });
  }
  syncLyric.addPhrase(
      lyric[i], playerController.value.position.inMilliseconds);

  _scrollController.animateTo(i*90.0,
      curve: Curves.ease, duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 300));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `center` and `shrinkWrap: true`

```
    Center(
        child: new ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: list.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Text("Centered item");
                          },
                        ),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to do some math! *(Nooooo, not the mathssssss)*.

It seems as though your goToNext() function is called while the app is running, rather than during build time. This makes it a little easier - you can simply use `context.size`. Otherwise you'd have to use a LayoutBuilder and maxHeight.

You can then divide this in two to get the half, then add/subtract whatever you need to get your item positioned how you want (since you've specified it's height as 90 in the example, I assume you could use 45 to get what you want).

Here's an example you can paste into a file to run:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Wid());

class Wid extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Scrolling by time"),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: Container()),
            Container(
              height: 300.0,
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: ScrollsByTime(
                itemExtent: 90.0,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(child: Container()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollsByTime extends StatefulWidget {
  final double itemExtent;

  const ScrollsByTime({Key key, @required this.itemExtent}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ScrollsByTimeState createState() {
    return new ScrollsByTimeState();
  }
}

class ScrollsByTimeState extends State<ScrollsByTime> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      _scrollController.animateTo(
        (widget.itemExtent * timer.tick) - context.size.height / 2.0 + widget.itemExtent / 2.0,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.ease,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Center(child: Text("Item $index"));
      },
      itemExtent: widget.itemExtent,
      controller: _scrollController,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but with the horizontal listview. You should use ScrollController and NotificationListener. When you receive endScroll event you should calculate offset and use scroll controller animateTo method to center your items.

```
class SwipeCalendarState extends State<SwipeCalendar> {
  List<DateTime> dates = List();
  ScrollController _controller;
  final itemWidth = 100.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
    for (var i = 1; i < 365; i++) {
      var date = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: i));
      dates.add(date);
    }

    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[buildListView()],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onStartScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics) {

  }

  void _onUpdateScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics){

  }

  void _onEndScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics){
    print("scroll before = ${metrics.extentBefore}");
    print("scroll after = ${metrics.extentAfter}");
    print("scroll inside = ${metrics.extentInside}");
    var halfOfTheWidth = itemWidth/2;
    var offsetOfItem = metrics.extentBefore%itemWidth;
    if (offsetOfItem < halfOfTheWidth) {
      final offset = metrics.extentBefore - offsetOfItem;
      print("offsetOfItem = ${offsetOfItem} offset = ${offset}");
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50), (){
        _controller.animateTo(offset, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.linear);
      });
    } else if (offsetOfItem > halfOfTheWidth){
      final offset = metrics.extentBefore + offsetOfItem;
      print("offsetOfItem = ${offsetOfItem} offset = ${offset}");
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50), (){
        _controller.animateTo(offset, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.linear);
      });
    }
  }

  Widget buildListView() {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
        if (scrollNotification is ScrollStartNotification) {
          _onStartScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
        } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
          _onUpdateScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
        } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
          _onEndScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
        }
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: dates.length,
          controller: _controller,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            var item = dates[i];
            return Container(
              height: 100,
              width: itemWidth,
              child: Center(
                child: Text("${item.day}.${item.month}.${item.year}"),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO the link you have posted had some wheel like animation. Flutter provides this type of animation with [ListWheelScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html) and rest can be done with the fade in animation and change in font weight with ScrollController.